# Search in MySQL - Separated Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a small script in PHP to get data from a MySQL Database.
In my database 'companies' is a column called category where i store my the companies' categories in. For example "1|2" or just "2".

Now i want to search for "2" and my database shall return those two entries with the "1|2" and "2" - but that is my problem. 
I tried it with LIKE % etc. but nothing worked as i hoped.

Does anyone may help me out with my small PHP script?

Comment: Show us the query you're trying... using LIKE '%2%' should do it...

Comment: use [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)

Comment: thank you diEcho. RLIKE solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's a bad idea to store categories in the way you do.
If you use `LIKE "%2"` or `LIKE "%2%"` or `LIKE "2"` statements to get compnaies wich belong to category "2", you will receive companies with categories e.g. `21|12`.

It'd be better to take categories away from company table. And add 2 new tables: category(id, name) and company_category(id, compnay_id, category_id). This is how it has to be in RDMS. 
But if you have weighty arguments why you do so - it is you deal.

In this I'd suggest wrapping categories in additional `|`-symbol to get `|1|2|` or `|1|3|23|` and using `LIKE "%|2|%"` statement.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM cat_baza WHERE subsection = ".$row['id']." or subsection LIKE('%|".$row['id']."|%') or subsection LIKE('".$row['id']."|%') or subsection LIKE('%|".$row['id']."');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE category LIKE %2% AND NOT LIKE '%|%'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE category='2' OR category LIKE '%|2' OR category LIKE '2|%'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE category REGEXP '.*2.*'
```

Regex should work